# Grouping null and empty values as one in sql

Tags: sql

I have a query which provides a breakdown of different categories applied to things in the database:

```
select categories, count(*) from products 
group by categories
```

The data comes like this:

```
NULL                56
                    42
FooCategory         12
BlahCategory        2
```

I would like to group `NULL` and `<blank>`

```
NoCategory          98
FooCategory         12
BlahCategory        2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
select categories, 
case when categories is null or categories = ' ' 
then 'noCategory' else categories end as grouped,
count(*) 
from products 
group by grouped
```

Comment: This looks good to me, though I'd probably trim the column and compare to an empty string to match either '' or all whitespace.

Answer (score 8):

try

```
select ISNULL(categories,'') as Categories, count(*) from products 
group by ISNULL(categories,'')
```

**UPDATE**

see here for parameters required

[ISNULL ( check_expression , replacement_value )](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx)